# C initialise 3D array with values

Tags: c, arrays, 3d

I'm trying to initialise all elements of a 3D array "A". The array consists of 2000x100x4 integer elements of the 3D array and is stored in row-major order. Each index at position [i,j,k] in "A" must be initialised with the value i*i*i + j*j*j.
How can I do this using for loops? Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't be that hard eh. Why don't you try something and get back to us if you have a problem?

Comment: @netcoder may be he do not know even the way to define a 3d array in C. so that why he is asking the question

Comment: Should have tested it before asking the question. Sorry guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not something hard to do:

```
int A[2000][100][4];
int i,j,k;
for (i=0;<2000;i++)
{
    for (j=0;j<100;j++)
    {
        for (k=0;k<4;k++)
        {
            A[i][j][k] = i*i*i + j*j*j;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for(i=0;i<2000;i++)
  for(j=0;j<100;j++)
    for(k=0;k<4;k++)
       A[i][j][k]= (i*i*i) + (j*j*j);
```

I hope I understood your question correctly. Or were you looking for something else?